# Seaborn barplot with regression line

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression, bar-chart, seaborn

Is there a way to add a regression line to a barplot in seaborn where the x axis contains pandas.Timestamps?

For example, overlay a trendline in this bar plot below. Am looking for the most efficient way to do this:

```
seaborn.set(style="white", context="talk")
a = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict({'Attendees': {pandas.Timestamp('2016-12-01'): 10,
  pandas.Timestamp('2017-01-01'): 12,
  pandas.Timestamp('2017-02-01'): 15,
  pandas.Timestamp('2017-03-01'): 16,
  pandas.Timestamp('2017-04-01'): 20}})
ax = seaborn.barplot(data=a, x=a.index, y=a.Attendees, color='lightblue', )
seaborn.despine(offset=10, trim=False)
ax.set_ylabel("")
ax.set_xticklabels(['Dec', 'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Related, but no exact duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558128/using-datetimes-with-seaborns-regplot

Answer (score 8):

Seaborn barplots are categorical plots. Categorical plots cannot directly be used for regression, because the numeric values would not fit. The usual matplotlib bar plots however use numeric data.

An option is to plot a matplotlib barplot and seaborn regplot in the same graph.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(5,9,13)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(len(x)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(x,y, width=0.1, color="lightblue", zorder=0)
sns.regplot(x=x, y=y, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylim(0, None)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Since seaborn's barplot uses the integers from 0 to number of bars as indizes, one can also use those indizes for a regression plot on top of seaborn bar plot.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas

sns.set(style="white", context="talk")
a = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict({'Attendees': {pandas.Timestamp('2016-12-01'): 10,
  pandas.Timestamp('2017-01-01'): 12,
  pandas.Timestamp('2017-02-01'): 15,
  pandas.Timestamp('2017-03-01'): 16,
  pandas.Timestamp('2017-04-01'): 20}})
ax = sns.barplot(data=a, x=a.index, y=a.Attendees, color='lightblue' )
# put bars in background:
for c in ax.patches:
    c.set_zorder(0)
# plot regplot with numbers 0,..,len(a) as x value
sns.regplot(x=np.arange(0,len(a)), y=a.Attendees, ax=ax)
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=False)
ax.set_ylabel("")
ax.set_xticklabels(['Dec', 'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - makes sense. What I am trying to do is show a bar chart with attendance by month, and overlay a regression line. I am probably not using the right chart type. Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: Well, my recommendation would be the above solution. If this doesn't help you, you need to share what you would like to have instead.

Comment: This does the trick. Given that this is a very common use case, I had hoped that there is a straightforward way to do this with regplot parameters, without having to "mask" the nature of the index or setting zorders.

Comment: I guess everyone thinks that his special use case is "very common". ;-)

Comment: Yup! Thanks a lot - much appreciated @ImportanceOfBeingErnest btw I love Wilde and that play ("earnest") in particular.