# Plotting time vs. another column

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a "time" column and another column with some integer values, lets call it "int" column. The time format is "MM/DD/YYYY Hour" such as "01/01/2016 00" or "01/01/2016 13"

Is there anyway to use scatter plot to plot the "int" values vs. "time"?

Thanks,

I tried matplotlib and the seaborn

```
plt.scatter(df_br.Date, df_br.CO2)

sb.regplot(data=df_br,x="Date", y="CO2");
```

Error for seaborn:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '01/01/2016 1401/01/2016 1501/01/2016 1601/01/2016 1701/01/2016 1801/01/2016 1901/01/2016 2001/01/2016 2101/01/2016 2201/01/2016 2301/02/2016 0001/02/2016 0101/02/2016 0201/02/2016 0301/02/2016 0401/02/2016 0501....
```

Error matplotlib:
 Takes a long time to run (I have not stopped it yet and it is working on that!)

Comment: your dates should be stored as datetime or timestamp objects, not strings

Comment: Try this line first `df_br= pd.to_datetime(df_br['Date'])`  Then plot.

Comment: Also based on your error, some of those date strings look a bit odd. If you post a complete example with sample data, that might help. You may need to specify a custom time format string given what I'm seeing right now.

Comment: @PaulH Well, I changed the format by using: pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H')                      Now, the plt.scatter works, but sb.regplot gives this error "DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation mean"

Comment: @ScottBoston Well, I changed the format by using: pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H')                      Now, the plt.scatter works, but sb.regplot gives this error "DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation mean"

Comment: @mayosten Well, I changed the format by using: pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H')                      Now, the plt.scatter works, but sb.regplot gives this error "DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation mean"

Comment: @PouyanEbrahimi Note that `regplot` does not support regression against datetimes as noted [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1066). You might consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558128/using-datetimes-with-seaborns-regplot) for ideas on workaround. I'm not an expert, but I believe it has to do with the fact that Seaborn is ultimately trying to build a first order linear regression between your two variables, and it doesn't know how to do that unless both are numerical types.